# How can a component provide other components?

Tags: c#, autofac

I want to have a component register other components in the registry as / after it's constructed. Let's say I have the following components:

```
interface IConfiguration 
{
    string SourceDirectory { get; }
    string TargetDirectory { get; }

    // other primitive-typed configuration parameters
}

class FileConfiguration : IConfiguration 
{
    // read parameters from some config file
}

class SourceDirectoryWrapper 
{
    public byte[] ReadFile(string filename) 
    {
        // read a file from the source directory
    }

    public string Directory { get; set; }
}

class TargetDirectoryWrapper 
{
    public byte[] WriteFile(string filename) 
    {
        // write a file into the source directory
    }

    public string Directory { get; set; }
}

class DirectoryWrapperFactory 
{
    public DirectoryWrapperFactory(IConfiguration config) 
    {
        var source = new SourceDirectoryWrapper { 
            Directory = config.SourceDirectory 
        };
        var target = new TargetDirectoryWrapper { 
            Directory = config.SourceDirectory 
        };
    }
}
```

The components `FileConfiguration` and `DirectoryWrapperFactory` can be registered as is usual.

However, what I'd like to accomplish is to somehow "outject" the `source` and `target` objects created in `DirectoryWrapperFactory`. The basic idea is that different environments might require different configuration providers. (And even if not, I think it's a good idea to put reading configuration parameters into a separate component.)

I'd also like to have `SourceDirectoryWrapper` and `TargetDirectoryWrapper` managed in the IoC container. In my case, mainly for convenience – I have an `EventSource` implementation that I need everywhere, so I inject it using property autowiring. Every object not in the IoC container needs to have it passed explicitly, which kind of bugs me.

So: is this possible with AutoFac? If so, how? I poked at the lifecycle events but most don't allow access to the registry after an object is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why DirectoryWrapperFactory needs to exist. You could just register SourceDirectoryWrapper and TargetDirectoryWrapper directly as part of normal wireup:

```
builder.Register(c => new SourceDirectoryWrapper { 
        Directory = c.Resolve<IConfiguration>().SourceDirectory 
    });

builder.Register(c => new TargetDirectoryWrapper { 
        Directory = c.Resolve<IConfiguration>().SourceDirectory 
    });
```

Comment: I'm using assembly scanning for everything except an EventSourceProxy implementation.. It's entirely possible it just made me  not realise I can register some of these things manually.